# Efficient way to calculate the time consumed by each user on a system

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Good day all, I have a mySQL table that looks like this:

```
|Id |username           |timestamp              |timestring     |
+---+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
|4  |user1              |2016-02-11 11:50:21    |20160211115021 |
|3  |user3              |2015-12-04 15:55:46    |20151204155546 |
|2  |user2              |2015-12-03 19:54:48    |20151203195448 |
|1  |user1              |2015-11-27 10:24:30    |20151127102430 |
+---+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
```

And this shows the access logs on a mutual exclusion panel (only one person each time can stay logged in).
What I'd like to do is to have some statistics, most of them are quite straight forward, but I have difficulties in calculating the time spent on the panel, I would like to know for each user, how much time he/she has "blocked" the system.

actually, I'm creating an array of usernames, in which I progressively sum all the seconds the user have from the "next" one (taken by id).

I feel this is very time consuming for the system, and I would like to have a more efficient way to do it, is there a way to obtain this using mySQL, or is better to build a new table in which I simply store all the usernames and add the time from time to time? Or is better to use PHP?

I must consider that the mySQL is a shared one, so my resources aren't limitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would create a subquery that joins your table on itself using the id field, where the id from the right hand side table is greater than the id on the left hand side and get the min(timestamp) from the right hand side table. In the outer query just sum up the difference between the the 2 timestamps:

```
select t.username, sum(t.endtime-t.starttime) as seconds
from
    (select t1.id, t1.username, t1.timestamp as starttime, min(t2.timestamp) as endttime
    from yourtable t1
    left join yourtable t2 on t1.id<t2.id
    group by t1.id, t1.username, t1.starttime) t
group by t.username
```

If you know that there are no gaps in the id field, then you can simplify your query:

```
select t1.username, sum(t2.timestamp-t1.timestamp) as second 
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2 on t1.id+1=t2.id
group by t1.username
```

Comment: looks really nice, I cannot think about it in any way (I'm not so experienced, and I can at least make some joins), I'll try it just to understand how it perform, but looks really neat.

Comment: @RickJames you mean the 2nd one because the 1st one would still work. And I did point it out that the 2nd solution only works if there is no gap in the ids.